# Vert.X with Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

I am a beginner in Vert.X and as per the documentation it is mentioned that Vert.X sharedSet and Map supports only immutable objects across verticles. If in case I want to share a java object, (assuming I am using Java based verticles) across verticles or modules what is the recommended approach? Can I use a hazelcast distributed hash table for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think you should try a different approach, otherwise you will be involved in one of the strongest points Vert.x is trying to alleviate: concurrency troubles. If I would have that *requirement* I would use something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) to have a really fast, centralized, volatile store I can access and share *something*. Maybe this doesn't answer your question, but pointing to a different approach...anyway, try to stay away from "shared state". Good luck!

Comment: Upvoted, although the case for Redis is moot. The OP could still use Hazelcast but instead store non-Java-serialized representation of their object, ie store data instead of objects the same way they would do with Redis but in-memory and with the Hazelcast cluster instead of the Redis one.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ if I want use Hazelcast structures (like Map) anyway, is it possible?

Comment: Indeed! A plus would be that you have the so-called "Hazelcast grid", hence your data is distributed among the nodes in a cluster (if any); quite convenient for scaling both: available storage and processing power. Redis also can do something "similar" though...but you know!